# How to get cropped image as an output in Winforms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an image with a black background. I am only interested in the foreground. In the image few upper as well as lower rows are black. I have got the row numbers respectively.

Now what I want is to get those rows deleted. I have managed to get the output in resultant picture box, but after relevant rows getting displayed it also displays the rows after which was there in input image. How can I use Tranparent function on these rows so that I can get only relevant part of the image. I am attaching the snapshot from which it will be more clear.

[image: The output I got is as shown in image]

Comment: Shall we guess?  Or would you like to show us what you are currently doing to get that result?

Comment: I got that that .Made a new bitmap with cropped dimension and then assigned it to resultant picturebox.Now I want to do more refining in which only the foreground object should come.